# Builder pattern for python lists

Tags: python, builder

I just spent some time confused why the following were returning `None`:

```
newList =  myList.extend(anotherList)
```

So it appears the `extend` is an in-place mutator *only*.  Is that all we're left with here .. i.e. is there any `builder` pattern for python `lists` ?

Comment: Why not `newList = myList + anotherList`?

Comment: You're right.  The reason this came about:  the second operand had earlier been a single element. Python uses a different syntax completely for single elements (must use `extend`)

Comment: @javadba for single elements, you neednt use extend. For a single element `x`, you can do `newlist = oldlist + [x]`. Just wrap that single element in a list. Its horribly inefficient, as it creates a gratuitous amount of temporary lists if used a lot, but if you don't care about that then its ok.

Comment: @PaulRooney I did see that .. and do care about performance.. so it seems `extend` is what it needs to be..

Comment: The other thing to consider is instead of lists use generators. I don't know what your particular use case is, so I cant suggest anything concrete.

Comment: @javadba extend also requires a list as argument. What you may be referring to is append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CoryKramer said: just use `+` ..

This would seem very (*very*..) obvious except that I had tried

`list1 + element1`

for another code snippet and that does *not* work.  There is only

`list1 + *list2*`